# How to change integer variable via boolean function in Dart

Tags: function, dart

When I'm using boolean function to modify some list it does work:

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> list = [];

  changeList(list);

  print("list outside func $list");
}

bool changeList(List<int> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }
  print("list inside func $list");
  return true;
}
```

But with the integer it doesnt and the value changes only inside the function:

```dart
void main() {
  int counter = 0;

  changeCounter(counter);

  print("counter outside func $counter");
}

bool changeCounter(counter) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    counter += 1;
  }
  print("counter inside func $counter");
  return false;
}
```

Is there any simple solution to modify the integer variable with boolean function the same as list?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a reference of the list to the function. You pass the integer value to the function, not a reference, so the initial variable outside of the function won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Dart language does not allow you to pass primitive types by reference

So you can create a primitive wrapper like this

```
void main() {
  IntegerWrapper counter = IntegerWrapper(0);

  changeCounter(counter);

  print("counter outside func $counter");
}

bool changeCounter(counter) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    counter.value += 1;
  }
  print("counter inside func $counter");
  return false;
}

class IntegerWrapper{
  int value;
  IntegerWrapper(this.value);

  String toString(){
    return value.toString();
  }
}
```